# How can I create a dynamic dictionaries in Python using a CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary, append

The problem is simple, I have a CSV file with four columns I wanted to value of the first column and make that into a dictionary in my python script. I don't want to add values to the dictionary dates of tasks completed.

The CSV data for this is found in a file called VC.csv, for example this:

```
24M Technologies,Series A,8/19/10
24M Technologies,Grant,8/16/10
2B Energy,Private Equity,3/18/14
2B Energy,Series B,3/18/14
2B Energy,Unattributed VC,5/1/08
3GSolar Photovoltaics,Series A,12/17/12
3sun Group,Growth Equity,3/3/14
3Tier Group,Series C,11/17/08
```

The end result I would like to have are dictionaries that are like this when I print them.

For example

```
>>> print 3TierGroup
>>>
>>>{'company': '2B Energy', 'Private Equity': '3/18/14', 'Series B': '3/18/14', 'Unattributed VC': '05/01/08'}
```

Where my problem is is trying to loop trough and add more to a already defined dictionary. Instead of appending I'm guessing I'm recreating and overwriting the loop every pass.  What I get as a result is `{'company': '2B Energy', 'Private Equity': '3/18/14'}`  I need the last line of my code to test to see if the dictionary is already present; if so it would append the additionally round dates to it.

Here is my code...

```
import csv

companyList =[]
transactionDates=[]
dictNames=[]

def fileNameCleaner(namer):
    namer = namer.replace(' ', '')
    namer = namer.replace(',','')
    namer = namer.replace('-','')
    namer = namer.replace('.','')
    namer = namer.replace('_','')
    namer = namer.replace('@','')
    namer = namer.replace('&','')
    return namer

with open('VC.csv', 'rb') as rawData:
    timelineData = csv.reader(rawData, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')      # Open CSV file and snag data
    for line in timelineData:  # Run through each row in csv
        companyList.append(fileNameCleaner(line[0])) # Create list and remove some special charcters
    companyList = list(set(companyList))    # Remove duplicates and Sort

for companyListRow in companyList:
    with open('VC.csv', 'rb') as rawDataTwo:
        timelineDataTwo = csv.reader(rawDataTwo, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for TList in timelineDataTwo:
            company = TList[0]
            finRound = TList[1]
            tranDate = TList[2]
            if companyListRow == fileNameCleaner(TList[0]):
                companyListRow = {'company':TList[0], finRound:tranDate }
                print companyListRow
```

Comment: I think that this kind of data would be best represented and queried in a SQL database (think SQLite) , since the financing types (seriesA, seriesB etc) will be repeated often and use up a lot of unnecessary storage. Also to query the data, finding out what funding, in what sequence would be best served in a  SQL database (one table for companies, one for funding types, one for the dates with the foreign keys being company and funding type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading in your data:

```
str1='''24M Technologies,Series A,8/19/10
24M Technologies,Grant,8/16/10
2B Energy,Private Equity,3/18/14
2B Energy,Series B,3/18/14
2B Energy,Unattributed VC,5/1/08
3GSolar Photovoltaics,Series A,12/17/12
3sun Group,Growth Equity,3/3/14
3Tier Group,Series C,11/17/08'''

list1= str1.split('\n')
print list1
```

I think you'd want just one dictionary (not many), so you can look up the data by company name, e.g. like this:

```
comps={}
for abc in list1:
    a,b,c=abc.split(',')
    if not a in comps:
        comps[a]= [[b,c]]
    else:
        comps[a].append([b,c])

for k,v in comps.iteritems():
    print k,v
```

Output:

```
3sun Group [['Growth Equity', '3/3/14']]
2B Energy [['Private Equity', '3/18/14'], ['Series B', '3/18/14'], ['Unattributed VC', '5/1/08']]
3Tier Group [['Series C', '11/17/08']]
3GSolar Photovoltaics [['Series A', '12/17/12']]
24M Technologies [['Series A', '8/19/10'], ['Grant', '8/16/10']]
```

The value of your dictionary entry would be a list of events, each event a list with first the type and then the date.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will sum up your company data, with just one pass through the CSV:

```
# define dict (to be keyed by company name) to accumulate company attributes from CSV file
company_data = {}

with open('VC.csv', 'rb') as rawData:
    # Open CSV file and snag data
    timelineData = csv.DictReader(rawData, delimiter=',', quotechar='"',
                                  fieldnames=['company','key','value'])

    # Run through each row in csv
    for line in timelineData:  
        name = filenameCleaner(line['company'])
        # get record for previously seen company, or get a new one with just the name in it
        rec = company_data.get(name, {'company': name})

        # add this line's key-value to the rec for this company
        rec[line['key']] = line['value']

        # stuff updated rec back into the overall summarizing dict
        company_data[name] = rec

# now get the assembled records by getting just the values from the summarizing dict
company_recs = company_data.values()
```